# I consist of three things. What am I?

Tags: riddle, science

> I am made up of 3 things,
>
> of which 2 things are same.
>
> I have a total of 10 something inside me.
>
> If you see me properly, I am a palindrome.

What am I?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Possibly you are

> Water

I am made up of 3 things, of which 2 things are same.

> You are made of 2 atoms of Hydrogen and 1 atom of Oxygen

I have total of 10 something inside me.

> A water molecule has 10 protons (8 from oxygen and 2 from hydrogen).

If you see me properly, I am a palindrome..

> Written chemically as $$ H - O - H$$ which is similar backwards even if the water molecule has a V-shape.

Comment: +1. I had this answer but only confused about  *I have total of 10 something inside me.*.

Comment: The 10 could be rot13 ryrpgebaf or as the total ... maybe there are other possibilities!

Comment: @Tom Heavy water also has 10 protons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium, Hydrogen always has 1 proton..

Comment: You are right Amruth - thanks for this - my mistake!

Answer (score 13):

You are

> The number decimal number 10 represented in base$_3$ notation (ternary) which is '101'.

I am made up of 3 things, of which 2 things are the same.

> 101 has three digits; Two 1's and One 0.

I have a total of 10 something in side of me.

> The unitless number '10' represents a total of 10 'somethings'.

If you see me properly, I am a palindrome.

> 10 can be represented multiple ways.  10 in base$_{10}$ (decimal) notation is not palindromic, but 101 base$_3$ (ternary) is a palindrome.

Comment: did you miss the [science] tag? Still +1 for a mathy answer!

Comment: @RedstoneGeek - Ahh, but mathematics **is** one of the types of science - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science - perhaps the tag needed to be "chemistry" ;)

Comment: A didn't notice the tag until after I had answered.  I was 'sure' the question had to be about number systems because of the emphasis on numbers and the only sometimes a palindrome clues.  So, I started at base2 and planned on working my way up through the bases until I found a match.  Hitting a solid answer at base3 was... pure serendipity.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> the number 101,

since

> there are three numbers in 101, two of the digits are the same, it's exactly the same backwards as it is forwards, and there is 10 in 101 as well as several 10's in the actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> Water ?

3 items - 2 are same :

> 2 Hydrogen , 1 oxygen.

10 something inside me :

> 10 protons (?)

Is a palindrome :

> H2O can be represented as HOH ?

Comment: It looks like this answer restates content that is already thoroughly expressed in another answer. In the future, please be sure to read through other answers on the site before adding your own. Thanks!