# Three Things Am I

Tags: riddle, wordplay

*The following riddle is not mine. I saw it in a shop that shares weekly riddles for people to solve. I solved this in around five minutes, so it should be relatively easy. I am sharing this because I quite love the writing style. Also, despite the similar title, [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46172/i-consist-of-three-things-what-am-i) is not a duplicate... well, not the riddle itself, to say the least...*

---

> > **Three things am I:**
>
> *Gentle enough to soothe your skin; 
>  Light enough to caress the sky; 
>  Hard enough to crack rocks.*

The answer is not three things, as I first thought. It is just one thing that has these three properties. Hope you enjoy! :D

Comment: Hahah! I received $3000$ rep, got a little bit over, gave away $100$ rep for a bounty, got a little bit under... and now I'm back on exactly $3000$ again. Thank you, @upvoter! Although I don't care too much about rep (sorry rep), it feels kinda good to have $3000$ :P

Comment: Gonna make that 3005 then :D

Comment: Nice riddle, but the line "well, not the riddle itself, to say the least..." kind of implied the great answer to the great riddle... +1 already still tho

Comment: @OmegaKrypton thank you! I appreciate you looking back at old stuff, haha :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say

> Water

*Gentle enough to soothe your skin;*

> Water is very gentle on skin

*Light enough to caress the sky;*

> Water reflects light from the sky, mirroring it

*Hard enough to crack rocks.*

> Water in motion is incredibly powerful, enough to break rocks or even concrete

Comment: Note: I posted this before seeing the other answer

Comment: I trust you. This has the correct explanations. (ROT13) V svefg gubhtug gur ebpxf jrer ersreevat gb fnaq, jurer va n ornpu, jngre pna jnfu hc gur fnaq ba gur fuber, naq ubj n glcvpny fxl vf oyhr; gubhtu gur pbhagre nggraqnagf ng gur evqqyr fubc rkcynvarq guvf gb zr whfg gur jnl lbh qvq. So... congratulations! You will be getting the tick. Do you want the tick now or tomorrow, or when exactly? :P

Comment: @user447343: I am honoured by your trust. It is interesting how different people think differently, and often get unique but still correct results! As for the tick, whenever you choose : )

Comment: Thank you! Also, you spelled the word "honoured" with a "u"... are you Aussie? (Too many 'merikans on this site, I'd be happy to see someone from Australia) :P

Comment: @user477343: Fraid not, I'm proudly South African : ). Sorry to disappoint you!

Comment: Well, congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 3):

It’s

> water

Gentle...:

> You take a bath with water, and it soothes your skin.

Light ...:

> As in rain

Hard...:

> Constant raining can crack rocks

Comment: Not quite for the last two explanations, but the first one is correct. You have the correct answer, anyways, but I won't accept until the explanations are correct too, given that this riddle is pretty easy for this site :P

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as most others here, but I thought like this:

> Water

*Gentle enough to soothe your skin;*

> Taking a bath or shower.

*Light enough to caress the sky;*

> Clouds slowly moving across the sky.

*Hard enough to crack rocks.*

> When water seeps into cracks in the mountain and then freezes, it expands and can crack rocks, called freeze-thaw.

Comment: That is a good explanation. I mean, clouds *are* made of water (vapour) at the end of the day, and clouds are light; though that freeze-thaw explanation is pretty good. I never knew about that, so that is very interesting! $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the other answers but I also thought this might be applicable:

> balm/bomb

Line 1:

> balm is spread on skin for soothing/therapeutic purposes

Line 2:

> bombs are lifted into the sky and dropped from above

Line 3:

> when they detonate, bombs destroy most things around them, including rocks

Comment: That is a good attempt. I like how they also kind of sound the same, too, haha. I would have upvoted if I did not reach my daily voting limit (DVL), but apart from that, great answer! :D

Comment: Upvoted. $(+1)$ :D